# Deleting content in Leaderboards in Google

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am using leaderboard in the Google play game services. How to delete the content(existing score history) in the leaderboard. It is important i do not want to delete the esisting leaderboard.

Kindly advice

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not delete leaderboards's history. Though, if you want to remove a particular player, there is an API method for that:

```
https://developers.google.com/games/services/management/api/players/hide
```